# How can I handle exceptions in a Pipeline when it has for loop?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a pipeline job which run some sequence of action (Eg; Build >> Run >> Report). I have put this sequence in a for loop as I can get a parameter which has list of value for which I should repeat the same sequence. Please find the sample code I have written.

```
    param_val = params.param_1
    param_list = param_val.split()
    for (int i = 0; i < size(param_list); ++i){
        item_value = param_list[i].trim()
        builds[i] ={
            stage('Build') {
                build 'Build', parameters: [string(name: 'item', value: item_value)]
            }
            stage('Run') {
               build 'Run', parameters: [string(name: 'item', value: item_value)]
            }
            stage('Reporting') {
               build 'Reporting', parameters: [string(name: 'item', value: item_value)]
            }
        }parallel builds
    }
```

Now when one of the stage in one of the for loop iteration fails also the complete pipeline is getting failed.I need to modify the same to fail only one iteration (sequence) and the other iterations should continue to run.
Sample: if I have 3 values in the param_val (one, two, three), I will have 3 sequence triggered.

```
Branch: 0 => Build(item:one) >> Run(item:one) >> Reporting(item:one)
Branch: 1 => Build(item:two) >> **Run(item:two)** >> Reporting(item:two)
Branch: 2 => Build(item:three) >> Run(item:three) >> Reporting(item:three)
```

If in this Branch 1: Run(item:two) fails,  All the iterations(Branch0, Branch2 and Branch1) will stop and pipeline job will be marked as failure.

I would like still pipeline to continue and do the other iterations(Branch0 and Branch2).
How can I do that ?

Comment: Does it not work if you use try, catch inside your loop for, and in the catch block you display the error?

Comment: Yeah you can solve this with `try/catch`. Give that a shot.